# meteorjs get data returned from server callback

Tags: meteor, callback

In meteor im trying to insert a new document by making a Meteor.call from the client. Everything is working ok, except that I want to return the id of create document to the client, so that i can redirect to the proper url.

I have something similar to this (client):

```
Meteor.call('scenarioCreate', scenarioObj, function(err, response) {

    if(err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return;
    }

    console.info(response);
});
```

On server:

```
Meteor.methods({

  'scenarioCreate': function(scenarioObj) {

    Scenarios.insert( scenarioObj, function(err, id) {

      console.info("new id: "+id);

      if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'Something went wrong');
      }

      return id;

    });
  }

});
```

From the server side i get the console log "new id: DDaq4aWsGf3fxG7RP", but I should get that same value on the client on the "**response**" value, but I always get undefined.

Can anybody explain to me why or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Meteor.methods` doesn't wait for your callback. Try this:

On server:

```
Meteor.methods({

  'scenarioCreate': function(scenarioObj) {

    var newId =  Scenarios.insert(scenarioObj);

    return newId;

  }

});
```

To catch any error, use `try/catch`

Note: If you still want to use callback, checkout [`fibers/future`](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers#futures).

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that you are returning `id` inside the callback for `insert`. That doesn't do anything. Then your second is not knowing that methods are synchronously executed. That would mean that you could only use the information available inside the callback using [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync). But that's besides the point. The `insert` function returns the new `_id`. Meaning you can do this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'scenarioCreate': function(scenarioObj) {
    return Scenarios.insert( scenarioObj );
  }
});
```